# Loading nested packages from local directories

Tags: package, composer-php, package-management

## The problem

There are three composer packages located in adjacent directories on a local disk: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`. They all have identical `composer.json` files (besides the package names):

```
{
    "name": "acme/foo",
#   "name": "acme/bar",
#   "name": "acme/baz",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../*"
        }
    ]
}
```

We want to use `foo` inside of `bar`. This works as expected.

```
$ cd /home/acme/bar
$ composer require acme/foo:dev-master
```

Then we want to use `bar` inside of `baz`. This fails.

```
$ cd /home/acme/baz
$ composer require acme/bar:dev-master
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for acme/bar dev-master -> satisfiable by acme/bar[dev-master].
    - acme/bar dev-master requires acme/foo dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

Why can't the composer find the `foo` package?

## Failed options

Things I've tried:

- Using a separate repository for each package
- Using absolute repository paths
- Disabling symlinks

None of these worked.

## Workarounds

I was able to find one workaround which I find a bit dirty. It turns out that when we first require `foo` and then `bar`, composer is able to resolve the dependencies.

## Related discussions

- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9145)

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) setting. It is set to `stable` by default, so it means that Composer will not install unstable dependencies, unless unstable constraint is explicitly specified in `require` section of root project. You may change this by adding to `composer.json` of your project:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

But it is not recommended, since it will affect all dependencies in your project, so you may get more unstable dependencies than you want. Explicitly requiring each unstable subdependency gives you more control, but in general, you should avoid using packages with unstable subdependencies (especially those defined as `dev-master` - it is only a matter of time when something will break).

Comment: Gonna give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I used to think that specifying `dev-master` explicitly is enough to make it kind of cascade.